# Error with active Record translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm getting an error when `db:reset`. I've read several posts about this, but none works for me.

The error says:

`translation missing: es.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid`

My `locales/es.yml` is:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        accepted: "must be accepted"
        blank: "can't be blank"
        confirmation: "doesn't match confirmation"
        empty: "can't be empty"
        equal_to: "must be equal to {{count}}"
        even: "must be even"
        exclusion: "is reserved"
        greater_than: "must be greater than {{count}}"
        greater_than_or_equal_to: "must be greater than or equal to {{count}}"
        inclusion: "is not included in the list"
        invalid: "is invalid"
        less_than: "must be less than {{count}}"
        less_than_or_equal_to: "must be less than or equal to {{count}}"
        not_a_number: "is not a number"
        odd: "must be odd"
        taken: "is already taken"
        too_long: "is too long (maximum is {{count}} characters)"
        too_short: "is too short (minimum is {{count}} characters)"
        wrong_length: "is the wrong length (should be {{count}} characters)"
```

Comment: The key `record_invalid` is not in your list. Try adding it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by copying all of the locales translations from rails locales repo to my es.yml.

https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml

Comment: This answer shouldn't be accepted as it doesn't explain the cause, it doesn't explain the solution either. The 1st comment to the question is a much better answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you install the `rails-i18n` gem, this will automatically include it in your rails app.

From the [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem readme:

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 5.1' # For 5.0.x, 5.1.x and 5.2.x
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0' # For 4.0.x
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 3.0' # For 3.x
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'master' # For 5.x
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'rails-4-x' # For 4.x
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'rails-3-x' # For 3.x
```

or run this command:

```
gem install rails-i18n -v '~> 5.1' # For  For 5.0.x, 5.1.x and 5.2.x
gem install rails-i18n -v '~> 4.0' # For 4.0.x
gem install rails-i18n -v '~> 3.0' # For 3.x
```